# How to center the text vertically using bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I'm creating a portfolio using bootstrap. For some reasons i can't get the text **vertically centered**. i have tried align-items-center and justify-content-center with no luck. Here is the code:

```
<div class="cover-container d-flex h-100 p-3 flex-column">
    <h1 style="font-weight: 650;">I'm <span style="color: #2075b6">ABC</span></h1>
    <h3>I'm a XYZ</h3>
</div>
```

I tried using align-items-center and justify-content-center with no luck.

Comment: Perhaps there are weird margin or padding with h1 and h3 that you think they are not centered.  adding align-items-center to the parent div should work

Answer (score 2):

To vertically center the text within the cover-container div using Bootstrap, you can try using the d-flex class along with the align-items-center and justify-content-center classes. Here's an updated version of your code:

```html
<div class="cover-container d-flex h-100 p-3 flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <h1 style="font-weight: 650;">I'm <span style="color: #2075b6">ABC</span></h1>
  <h3>I'm a XYZ</h3>
</div>
```

By adding the align-items-center and justify-content-center classes to the cover-container div along with the d-flex class, the text should be centered vertically within the container.

[exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6g4V.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center" style="min-height: 300px;">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
         <h1 style="font-weight: 650;">I'm <span style="color: #2075b6">ABC</span></h1>
         <h3>I'm a XYZ</h3>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

First create a container div for grid system in order to center the content. Then create a row and center the content vertically within the row using the 'align-items-center' class. Also create a column within the row and center the content horizontally using the 'text-center'class. Note that the min-height property ensures that the row has a minimum height, which allows the content to be centered both vertically and horizontally regardless of the height of the content.